# how to access weights of individual Neurons in the output layers in MLPs?

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, keras, multiclass-classification, mlp

im working on a neural network using Keras. Its an mlp(multi-layer perceptron). With  8 Neurons in the output layer. Is there a way I can access weights and biases of individual neurons of the output layer for every iteration?

Comment: Maybe you are looking for this https://itnspotlight.com/dissecting-keras-neural-networks-accessing-weights-and-hidden-layers/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The callback function can be used with  `model.layers[-1].get_weights()` to get weights per iteration.

```
weights=[]
getweights = LambdaCallback(on_epoch_end=lambda batch, logs: weights.append(model.layers[-1].get_weights()[1]))
model.fit(x, y, batch_size=5,epochs=10, callbacks=[getweights])
print(weights)
```

In the given code weights is a list which contains weight values for the first Neuron/class of output Layer.

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing you want something like this:

```py
model.layers[-1].get_weights()
```

Comment: how can I use this function for every iteration?